# Compute cumulative standard deviation in Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, standard-deviation

I have a numpy array and I am looking to compute **cumulative standard deviation** across the array elements. However, I cannot seem to find a Numpy function to achieve the same.

I was able to find a function in Pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.std.html), however converting the Numpy array to a Pandas series will add to the overall time taken.
Another alternative can be to implement a custom Python function for the computation, however time complexity wise, this solution will take even longer (since Python in itself is a slow language).

Can someone help me with a solution for computing cumulative standard deviation in the least time possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post an example of input and the expected output? Also, in the pandas page that you linked it states that it is equivalent to `numpy.std` so, why don't you use that?

Comment: @alec_djinn I think the linked page just says that numpy.std is related, not the same. numpy.std does not give a cumulative standard deviation. Instead it returns a single standard deviation for all the array elements

Comment: To give an example for my use-case: Suppose the array is [1, 2, 3]. Though the standard deviation for this array will be 0.81, the cumulative standard deviation will be different for each of the array elements: [0, 0.5, 0.81]. That is, till the first element the stdev is 0, till the second element stdev is 0.5 and till the third, it is 0.81

Comment: `ufunc` have an `accumulate`.  `cumsum` is `add.accumulate`.  I think `mean` has it, but I'd have to check.  Those should provide the building blocks for a `accumilate` version of `std`

Comment: From theory, is there a simple way of calculating `std` from the `std` of a list and a newly added value? Or does it have to be calculated fresh for the new list?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
arr = np.array([1,2,3])
r = [arr[:x].std() for x in range(1,len(arr)+1)]

print(r)

[0.0, 0.5, 0.816496580927726]
```

But honestly, the Pandas version will be for sure faster. Don't think casting a DataFrame is gonna take too much overhead. Just use pandas.

Comment: I wouldn't count on pandas being faster. Expanding may just use a python level iteration.